# Mobile site layout broken with posts containing videos

Tags: bug, mobile

When checking pages on a mobile with embedded videos, the text seems to overflow the box. There is also no horizontal scrollbar, thereby making reading the answer impossible (without switching to Desktop mode first).

Example page: [How do we know that the First Doctor was indeed the first?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65927/how-do-we-know-that-the-first-doctor-was-indeed-the-first)

Screenshot:
[image: Unreadable text]

Device: Samsung N7505, Android 4.3, Mobile Chrome 36.0.1985.135. Also broken within the stock browser as well.